# How do I aggregate on a raw field in Elasticsearch? The raw field appears to be unpopulated

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm trying to setup an aggregation on a raw field. I have a schema defined as:

```
my $result = $es->indices->create(
index   => 'events',
body => {
    #number_of_shards      => 3,
    #number_of_replicas    => 2,
    analysis => {
        analyzer => {
            default => {
                tokenizer   => 'standard',
                char_filter => ['html_strip'],
                filter      => [qw(standard lowercase stop asciifolding)],
            }
        }
    },
    event => {
        properties => {
            event_id => { type => 'integer' },
            escaped_name => { type => 'string', index => 'not_analyzed' },
            name => { type => 'string' },
            description => { type => 'string' },
            venue => {
                type => 'string',
                fields => {
                    raw => { type => 'string', index => 'not_analyzed' },
                },
            },
            escaped_venue => { type => 'string', index => 'not_analyzed' },
            address => { type => 'string' },
            postcode => { type => 'string' },
            type => { type => 'string' },
            tags => { type => 'string' }, 
            start_date => { type => 'date' },
            end_date => { type => 'date' },
            courses => {
                type => 'nested',
                include_in_parent => 1,
                properties => {
                    name => { type => 'string' },
                    distance => { type => 'integer' },
                    price => { type => 'integer' },
                },
            },
        }
    }
},
);
```

Okay, this is using the Perl API, but hopefully you get the idea.

If I look at the index, it seems okay to me:

```
  "events" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1417040345427",
        "uuid" : "Ep-7XxfTQIO8pN7CG67_JA",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
            "default" : {
              "char_filter" : [ "html_strip" ],
              "filter" : [ "standard", "lowercase", "stop", "asciifolding" ],
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "event" : {
          "properties" : {
            "tags" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "end_date" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "escaped_name" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "escaped_venue" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "courses" : {
              "type" : "nested",
              "include_in_parent" : "1",
              "properties" : {
                "distance" : {
                  "type" : "integer"
                },
                "name" : {
                  "type" : "string"
                },
                "price" : {
                  "type" : "integer"
                }
              }
            },
            "address" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "description" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "event_id" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "type" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "postcode" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "venue" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "fields" : {
                "raw" : {
                  "type" : "string",
                  "index" : "not_analyzed"
                }
              }
            },
            "start_date" : {
              "type" : "date"
            }
          }
        },
        "version" : {
          "created" : "1040099"
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "event" : {
        "properties" : {
          "address" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "courses" : {
            "properties" : {
              "distance" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "price" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "description" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "end_date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "escaped_name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "escaped_venue" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "event_id" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "postcode" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "start_date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "tags" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "type" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "venue" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've indexed two documents, which both contain a venue. Am I supposed to be able to select `venue.raw` using `_source` in a search? If I am, it doesn't seem to return anything:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/events/_search?pretty -d ' {
  "query": { "match_all": { } },
  "_source": ["venue.raw", "venue", "escaped_venue"]
}'
{
  "took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "events",
      "_type" : "event",
      "_id" : "AUnuL7oEm0fJj8toLjY5",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"escaped_venue":"Herne Hill Velodrome","venue":"Herne Hill Velodrome"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "events",
      "_type" : "event",
      "_id" : "AUnuL7nYm0fJj8toLjY4",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"escaped_venue":"Queen Elizabeth Olympic Park","venue":"Queen Elizabeth Olympic Park"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

I've also tried to aggregate on both the "venue.raw" field (and also "escaped_venue" as a test):

```
    my $search_args = {
        index => 'events',
        type => 'event',
        body => {
            aggs => {
                type => {
                    terms => {
                        field => 'type',
                    },
                },
                tags => {
                    terms => {
                        field => 'tags',
                    },
                },
                'escaped_venue' => {
                    terms => {
                        field => 'escaped_venue',
                    },
                },
                venue => {
                    terms => {
                        field => "venue.raw",
                    },
                },
                distance => {
                    range => {
                        field => 'distance',
                        ranges => [
                            { from => 0, to => 30 },
                            { from => 30, to => 50 },
                            { from => 50, to => 100 },
                            { from => 100, to => 150 },
                            { from => 150, to => 200 },
                            { from => 200 },
                        ],
                    },
                },
                price => {
                    range => {
                        field => 'price',
                        ranges => [
                            { from => 0, to => 10 },
                            { from => 10, to => 20 },
                            { from => 20, to => 30 },
                            { from => 30, to => 50 },
                            { from => 50 },
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    };
```

I don't get any results on the aggregation for "venue.raw" and I see analyzed results for "escaped_venue":

```
{
  _shards => { failed => 0, successful => 5, total => 5 },
  aggregations => {
    distance => {
      buckets => [
        {
          doc_count => 0,
          from => 0,
          from_as_string => "0.0",
          key => "0.0-30.0",
          to => 30,
          to_as_string => "30.0",
        },
        {
          doc_count => 1,
          from => 30,
          from_as_string => "30.0",
          key => "30.0-50.0",
          to => 50,
          to_as_string => "50.0",
        },
        {
          doc_count => 0,
          from => 50,
          from_as_string => "50.0",
          key => "50.0-100.0",
          to => 100,
          to_as_string => "100.0",
        },
        {
          doc_count => 1,
          from => 100,
          from_as_string => "100.0",
          key => "100.0-150.0",
          to => 150,
          to_as_string => "150.0",
        },
        {
          doc_count => 2,
          from => 150,
          from_as_string => "150.0",
          key => "150.0-200.0",
          to => 200,
          to_as_string => "200.0",
        },
        { doc_count => 0, from => 200, from_as_string => "200.0", key => "200.0-*" },
      ],
    },
    escaped_venue => {
      buckets => [
        { doc_count => 1, key => "elizabeth" },
        { doc_count => 1, key => "herne" },
        { doc_count => 1, key => "hill" },
        { doc_count => 1, key => "olympic" },
        { doc_count => 1, key => "park" },
        { doc_count => 1, key => "queen" },
        { doc_count => 1, key => "velodrome" },
      ],
      doc_count_error_upper_bound => 0,
      sum_other_doc_count => 0,
    },
    price => {
      buckets => [
        {
          doc_count => 0,
          from => 0,
          from_as_string => "0.0",
          key => "0.0-10.0",
          to => 10,
          to_as_string => "10.0",
        },
        {
          doc_count => 0,
          from => 10,
          from_as_string => "10.0",
          key => "10.0-20.0",
          to => 20,
          to_as_string => "20.0",
        },
        {
          doc_count => 0,
          from => 20,
          from_as_string => "20.0",
          key => "20.0-30.0",
          to => 30,
          to_as_string => "30.0",
        },
        {
          doc_count => 2,
          from => 30,
          from_as_string => "30.0",
          key => "30.0-50.0",
          to => 50,
          to_as_string => "50.0",
        },
        { doc_count => 0, from => 50, from_as_string => "50.0", key => "50.0-*" },
      ],
    },
    tags => {
      buckets => [
        { doc_count => 2, key => "charity" },
        { doc_count => 1, key => "closed" },
        { doc_count => 1, key => "road" },
      ],
      doc_count_error_upper_bound => 0,
      sum_other_doc_count => 0,
    },
    type => {
      buckets => [{ doc_count => 2, key => "sportive" }],
      doc_count_error_upper_bound => 0,
      sum_other_doc_count => 0,
    },
    venue => {
      buckets => [],
      doc_count_error_upper_bound => 0,
      sum_other_doc_count => 0,
    },
  },
  hits => {
    hits => [
      {
        _id     => "AUnuL7oEm0fJj8toLjY5",
        _index  => "events",
        _score  => 0.067124054,
        _source => {
                     address       => "104 Burbage Road, London",
                     courses       => [
                                        { distance => 48, name => "The Short Route", price => 40 },
                                        { distance => 104, name => "The Medium Route", price => 46 },
                                        { distance => 166, name => "The Long Route", price => 48 },
                                      ],
                     description   => "Formerly known as Ride Around London, the Financial Times London Cycle Sportive, supporting Access Sport will take place on Sunday 30 June and the route takes in many important landmarks from London\xE2\x80\x99s Olympic history including a unique finish on the 1948 Olympic Velodrome at Herne Hill.",
                     end_date      => "2013-06-30",
                     escaped_name  => "financial_times_london_cycle_sportive",
                     escaped_venue => "Herne Hill Velodrome",
                     event_id      => 2,
                     name          => "Financial Times London Cycle Sportive",
                     postcode      => "SE24 9HE",
                     start_date    => "2013-06-30",
                     tags          => ["charity"],
                     type          => "sportive",
                     venue         => "Herne Hill Velodrome",
                   },
        _type   => "event",
      },
      {
        _id     => "AUnuL7nYm0fJj8toLjY4",
        _index  => "events",
        _score  => 0.04746387,
        _source => {
                     address       => "London",
                     courses       => [{ distance => 161, price => 48 }],
                     description   => "Taking a cue from the London Marathon, amateur cyclists will also participate in the Prudential RideLondon-Surrey 100 \xE2\x80\x93 a 100-mile challenge on the same closed roads as the professionals, with the added incentive of raising money for good causes. To capture it all, the best action will be broadcast live on TV in the UK and internationally, to be seen by an audience of millions.",
                     end_date      => "2013-08-04",
                     escaped_name  => "prudential_ridelondon_surrey_100",
                     escaped_venue => "Queen Elizabeth Olympic Park",
                     event_id      => 1,
                     name          => "Prudential RideLondon-Surrey 100",
                     postcode      => "E20 2ST",
                     start_date    => "2013-08-04",
                     tags          => ["charity", "closed road"],
                     type          => "sportive",
                     venue         => "Queen Elizabeth Olympic Park",
                   },
        _type   => "event",
      },
    ],
    max_score => 0.067124054,
    total => 2,
  },
  timed_out => bless(do{\(my $o = 0)}, "JSON::XS::Boolean"),
  took => 12,
}
```

I also see an empty bucket for the "venue.raw" aggregation if I perform it via cURL.

What's going on here? Do I need to do something explicit to populate the raw field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was not creating the index correctly after trying to port to the latest version of Elasticsearch.

It should have been:

```
my $result = $es->indices->create(
    index   => 'events',
    body => {
        #number_of_shards      => 3,
        #number_of_replicas    => 2,
        analysis => {
            analyzer => {
                default => {
                    tokenizer   => 'standard',
                    char_filter => ['html_strip'],
                    filter      => [qw(standard lowercase stop asciifolding)],
                }
            }
        },
        mappings => {
            event => {
                properties => {
                    event_id => { type => 'integer' },
                    escaped_name => { type => 'string', index => 'not_analyzed' },
                    name => { type => 'string' },
                    description => { type => 'string' },
                    venue => {
                        type => 'string',
                        fields => {
                            raw => { type => 'string', index => 'not_analyzed' },
                        },
                    },
                    escaped_venue => { type => 'string', index => 'not_analyzed' },
                    address => { type => 'string' },
                    postcode => { type => 'string' },
                    type => { type => 'string' },
                    tags => { type => 'string' }, 
                    start_date => { type => 'date' },
                    end_date => { type => 'date' },
                    courses => {
                        type => 'nested',
                        include_in_parent => 1,
                        properties => {
                            name => { type => 'string' },
                            distance => { type => 'integer' },
                            price => { type => 'integer' },
                        },
                    },
                },
            }
        }
    },
);
```

Now the aggregation works as expected.